# Does PHP file_get_contents() automatically turn contents into ASCII?

Tags: php, text, file-get-contents

Let's say I want to know the encoding of a text file,
does PHP file_get_contents automatically turn contents into ASCII?

```
<pre>
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('./test.txt', true);

echo $file."<br>".mb_detect_encoding($file);
echo "<br>";
$file = file_get_contents('./test (2).txt', true); 

echo $file."<br>".mb_detect_encoding($file);
echo "<br>";
$file = file_get_contents('./test (3).txt', true);

echo $file."<br>".mb_detect_encoding($file);


?>
```

Comment: Nope, *PHP* doesn't care - it has no need to.  So however the text was encoded to begin with will be what you're working with.  Either that or it has been modified for transport - *(mind reading mode)*... are you by any chance using an *FTP* client in *ASCII* rather than binary mode?

Comment: @Emissary Heh... one of the many reasons my old projects all use ASCII - anything outside of that is encoded as an HTML entity before being sent to the server (and any non-ASCII input is rejected). Ah, how stupid I was to think that sweeping the problem under the carpet was a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

It does not convert the contents to ASCII. Because it is only getting the contents of a file it has no need to.
More information is at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: While links are great, the resources can be moved or deleted. It is a good idea to provide explanations in the post in addition of the links.